# Getting an API response and using it in another call, simultaneously (angular)

Tags: javascript, angular

I am starting to learn Angular 4 and I thought the bungie.net API was a nice playground to fidget with.

What I am trying to do here is: when the user enters their display name (gamertag or psn id) they'd get an in-page dashboard for stats.

I could achieve that by making them put their "membershipId" but obviously no one knows that and you need to go to the bungie.net sie to find out yours while you always know your display name.

Their API got a endpoint to return the membership id:

https://www.bungie.net/platform/Destiny/Help/HelpDetail/GET?uri=%7bmembershipType%7d%2fStats%2fGetMembershipIdByDisplayName%2f%7bdisplayName%7d%2f

Problem is that I don't know how to use the returned membership id to then get a response of the stats through this endpoint that supports only membershipIds and not display names. ( https://www.bungie.net/platform/destiny/help/HelpDetail/GET?uri=Stats%2fAccount%2f%7bmembershipType%7d%2f%7bdestinyMembershipId%7d%2f )

Here's some sample code that I am using for now (some is hardcoded since I couldn't achieve the below).

service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
import { Http, Response, RequestOptions, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';



@Injectable()
export class bungieService {
  private query: string;
  private API_URL_PLAYER_ID: string = environment.BUNGIE_API_URL_PLAYER_ID;
  private URL_PLAYER_ID: string = this.API_URL_PLAYER_ID + '';
  private API_URL_PLAYER_STATS: string = environment.BUNGIE_API_URL_PLAYER_STATS;
  private URL_PLAYER_STATS: string = this.API_URL_PLAYER_STATS;


  constructor (private _http: Http) {}


    getPlayerId(query) {
        let headers: Headers = new Headers();
        var apiKey = "786eefe6a85b4bac9858f71dd4006dc9";
        headers.append("X-API-Key", apiKey);
        let opts: RequestOptions = new RequestOptions();
        opts.headers = headers;
        return this._http.get(this.URL_PLAYER_STATS + '4611686018430120182/' , opts).map(res=> res.json());
    }


}
```

component ts (slightly different from the vanilla one but the searchPlayer function is the same)

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { bungieService } from '../shared/bungie.service';
import { Http, Response, RequestOptions, Headers } from '@angular/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-nexus',
  templateUrl: './nexus.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nexus.component.css']
})
export class NexusComponent implements OnInit {
    playerId: any[];
    playerIdFound: boolean = false;
    playerSummary: any[];
    playerSummaryFound: boolean = false;

        handleSuccessPlayerId(data) {
        this.playerIdFound = true;
        this.playerId = data;
        console.log(data.Response);
    }

                handleSuccessPlayerChar(data) {
        this.playerSummaryFound = true;
        this.playerSummary = data;
        console.log(data.Response.data.characters);
    }


  constructor(private _bungieService: bungieService) { }

    searchPlayer (query: string) {
    return this._bungieService.getPlayerId(query).subscribe(
        data => this.handleSuccessPlayerId(data),
        error => console.log(error),
        () => console.log("complete!!!!")
        )
  }

      searchPlayersChar (query: string) {
    return this._bungieService.getPlayerSummary(query).subscribe(
        data => this.handleSuccessPlayerChar(data.Response.data.characters),
        error => console.log(error),
        () => console.log("complete!!!!")
        )
  }



  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

component html:

```
 <div class="container">

<div class="well"  style="margin-top:5rem;">
    <input class="search" [(ngModel)]="searchQueryPlayer" placeholder="search for data">
    <button (click)="searchPlayers(searchQueryPlayer)" type="button">Find data</button>
    <span>{{ players.Response.data.membershipType }}</span> 
</div>
```

environment:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  BUNGIE_API_KEY: 'myApiKey',
  BUNGIE_API_URL_PLAYER_ID: 'https://www.bungie.net/Platform/Destiny/2/Stats/GetMembershipIdByDisplayName/',
  BUNGIE_API_URL_PLAYER_STATS: 'https://www.bungie.net/Platform/Destiny/Stats/Account/2/',
};
```

Comment: How are you subscribing to getPlayerId in component

Comment: Thanks @RahulSingh , forgot to add the main ts ahah